# How to get the actual size of selected files and folders?

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
long sizeOfDirectory = FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(selectedFile);
```

This isn't generating the actual size of selected files and folders, but gives only a value which is less than actual value.

I am selecting more than one folder at once.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: *"Give just only a value which is less than actual value"* - When compared to what?

Comment: Please share actual ouput and expected output.

Comment: When comparing with the actual value .

Comment: @TeranceWijesuriya How do you calculate the actual value?

Comment: @TAsk This is the actual size of selected folders 410 MB but the code bring me this 355.458 MB .

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just get the actual through the properties .

Comment: @TeranceWijesuriya Based on my testing I get `FileUtils` = 422.85mb, Windows Size = 422mb/Size on Disk = 425mb... and `FileUtils` = 25.23gb; Windows size = 25.2gb/Size on Disk = 25.3gb; So depending on which value you are trying to compare, you might get a different value?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Actually I am selecting 2 folders, then this issue happens.

Comment: *"I just get the actual through the properties ."*  Actual Windows properties for files will list down to the last byte.  Looking at one right now shows `Size: 52.8KB (55,122 bytes)` while **`Size on disk: 64.0 KB (65,536 bytes)`**  which number are you looking at and what is the exact number of bytes?

Comment: That's because `JFileChooser#getSelectedFile` will only return ONE.  You need to use `JFileChooser#getSelectedFiles` and loop over them, calling `FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory` for each file and summing the results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Actually I am selecting 2 folders, then this issue happens

That's because `JFileChooser#getSelectedFile` will only return ONE.  You need to use `JFileChooser#getSelectedFiles` and loop over them, calling `FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory` for each file and summing the results

```
File[] selectedFiles = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
long sizeOfDirectory = 0;
for (File file : selectedFiles) {
    sizeOfDirectory += FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(file);
}
```

(You should also beware that `getSelectedFile` and `getSelectedFiles` may return `null`)